# CasperJS - Follow all links on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to automate a check for a parameter appending on all links on a given page. So my question is how to execute click event for all links follow their location and then run my checks?

My links look like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="track-me logo"></a>
```

And I'm appending a parameter on a click event, so the final URL becomes:

```
http://google.com?myParam=12345
```

I've tried quite few things but I think that the following solution is closest to the desired result:

```
var config = {
    url: 'http://linktomy.page',
    parameterValue: 12345
};

var links = [];

casper.start(config.url);

casper.then(function getLinks() {
    links = this.evaluate(function () {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        links = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function (link) {
            return link.getAttribute('href');
        });
        return links;
    });
});

casper.then(function () {
    this.each(links, function (self, link) {
        casper.thenClick("a[href='" + link + "']");

        casper.waitFor(function check() {
            return this.getCurrentUrl() !== config.url;
        }, function then() {
            console.log('NEW URL >>>> ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
        });
    });
});

casper.run(function () {
    this.exit();
});
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work? You've shown some code, but haven't described how it currently behaves. It looks to me that you have everything you need. How exactly doesn't this code accomplish what you're asking?

Comment: The URLs are generated with JavaScript and currently I get only the last URL location.

Comment: So, you have a completely different question, because you don't have a problem following all the links, but rather collecting all the links. Since you already received an answer to the first question, you need to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your actual problem. You could [edit] this question to clarify the actual issue, but this would invalidate the existing answer, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

i do it a bit another way and use to get the links "casper.getElementsAttribute" like that:

```
links = casper.getElementsAttribute(selector, 'href');
```

To prove the the links i call them in a while loop:

```
while (links.length > 0) {
    link = links.pop();
    (function(link){
        casper.then(function(){
           casper.echo("Checking link " + link);
        });
        casper.thenOpen(link, function() {
            title = casper.getTitle();
        });
        casper.then(function() {
             casper.waitForText(title);
        });
        casper.then(function() {
             casper.test.assertHttpStatus(200, "link '" + title + "' (title) - returns Http Status 200!");
        });     
    })(link);
}
```

This can surely be done nicer, but that work well for me. If anybody got a nicer way to do it, i'm interested too. :)
Hope it'll help you.

Comment: That would surely do the work if I don't build my links with JavaScript, unfortunately I do...